# Highcharts - Identify whether point lies on (within/inside) Chart from X/Y coordinates

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, titanium

I have a **point on the chart** by its x, y co-ordinates. **Without clicking** at this point, I want to identify if this point lies on the **chart's data section** (colored part of chart) that is being displayed. I think this will be a function used by the Highcharts library internally. But, can't seem to figure it out. 
Please note that neither any click or any events are triggered at this moment.

The charts that I will be using for display are Column, Line & Pie charts.

The purpose behind doing this is, I am identifying this point from the Titanium application layer on the mobile & then I intend to perform click operation after determining the position of selected point.

Comment: HighCharts src can be found [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/highcharts.src.js)

Comment: I think highcharts will render all its points visible. on the screen. if you give any min/max restrictions for the axis then there is a possibility for the point to go out of view. can please give a sample code for which you are looking out for a solution

Comment: No sample in specific. This logic can be applied to any HighChart.

Comment: Do you have zoom in your chart

Answer (score 1):

As @strikers said, you can loop over all points and compare `point.[x/y]` values with extremes set on axes (`[x/y]Axis.getExtremes()`).

However, if you want to check not values (wonder why..) but their pixel position, you can use `point.plot[X/Y]` and use `chart.isInsidePlot(point.plotX, point.plotY)`. But! points can have undefined that values, if isn't plotted within extremes, so again, you should use first solution.

Comment: By point on chart I mean the coloured Column or Colored Pie or Line Chart & not the canvas of Chart. By using function isInsidePlot, the entire bounds of the chart can be identified. [Trial Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/rckahale/cH6ma/)
For example, let me explain from graph. If I have x/y co-ordinate to any point on any column say Animals, I want to identify whether this selected coordinate is part of Animals or any coloured column. This is because, I will employ a conditional click based on the position inside the chart.

Comment: As said above, the point is selected on the Titanium layer by touch other than click (say double tap/double touch/longpress which is not supported by highchart)

Comment: Okay, so you have coordinates x/y for click/tap/whatever. And you want to check if this coordinates belongs to one of points? Then, as I said above use `point.plotX/Y` to find top left corner of shape. Last you have point shape options in `point.shapeArgs.width/height` to check if your coordinates are within that point shape. And if are, then call your events.